# 90s military spaceship sci-fi pilot/movie

Tags: story-identification, tv

It could have been a pilot or a tv movie. I think it aired on broadcast tv mid to late 90s. The main plot point I remember (It has been a while so some may be a bit off):

- Starts with Military Ball, Jr officer approaches Lady, who turns out to be his commanding officer.
- All hands on deck, heading to space battle far away.
- All humans (no aliens).
- Ship breaks down en-route to battle.
- Engineer goes inside giant horizontal cylinder engine cavity.
- One of the crew turns on the engine. Engineer gets fried.
- Space Trial! Vote by dropping black or white marble into a vase.
- One lady is not shy about which marble goes in the vase.
- All black marbles, saboteur dumped out the airlock.
- Engine fixed, head back to giant space battle.

Comment: I'm not convinced these are duplicate. Sure the answers are the same, but things we remembered about it were radically different. I didn't recognize it from his description. To be fair, we both remembered it rather differently than it actually was...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 1996 hit film "[Star Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Command_(film))".

The scene with the marbles is here

Comment: For the record, this film is garbage. Instead of watching this, I'd suggest you spend your hour and a half learning conversational Japanese, tidying out your garage or learning to cook the perfect omelette.

Comment: One might think you'd taken a few too many of these "hits"...

Comment: @jeffronicus - Sarcasm is the only thing that eases the pain

Comment: Yep, those are the marbles. I'm glad I found them. The synopsis/review on IMDB suggests I got quiet a few of those plot points wrong. I'm thinking I'll need to watch it to see how fallible my memory is.