# Late 90s scifi space movie where astronauts on a long journey vote to execute someone using marbles

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie on TV as a kid.  Not sure if it was a direct to TV movie or not.

What I do remember is that a team of astronauts were taking a long voyage from Earth (I think) to a distant planet.  At some point one of the crew tries to kill someone and they vote on whether or not to execute him using black and white marbles.  He is unanimously found guilty.

Right before arriving at their destination they get into a firefight and are rescued before they can be totally destroyed.

This was like 20 years ago. I wanna say between 96 and 01. I don't remember much but the trial with the marbles was very distinct.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170044/90s-military-spaceship-sci-fi-pilot-movie Star Command?

Comment: I initially read this as saying the marbles were the execution method. You may want to reword this to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

There is a scene like this in the 1996 movie 'Star Command' or 'In the Fold'. All I remember is that it was a military ship in combat and one crew member somehow betrayed the others. He commits suicide before the sentence can be carried out.